# Likelihood function for number of slots taken over slots available

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, likelihood

I have a study in which I am comparing the number of outpatient visits a certain surgery experiencse in a same period in two different years; the total number of visits is a limited by the number of slots per week.

The periods cover 2-3 months, and to simplify the model I summed up the number of visits in these period and the total number of slots. I don't think this assumption introduces too much bias because the numerosity is very low and the visit slots are never filled up.

I am approaching this from a Bayesian point of view and I applied a binomial model, conditional on the number of available spots in a certain period, for example:

$$
Visit \sim Binomial(Slots, p) \\ 
logit(p) = \beta_{year} \\
\beta_{year} = some\_prior()
$$

My question is if the Binomial likelihood is appropriate. Patients showing up requesting a visit are more or less independent events, but the number of slots I'm not sure can be intended as the number of independent trials. Is there a more appropriate likelihood function? Would the difference be noticeable?

Comment: I have some ideas, that might be helpful but they might depend on conditions that not hold in your case. I'll give it a chance to write them down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that $Visit \sim Bin(Slots,p)$ is appropriate because a single visit might happen independently if there is a slot or not. I do not know the whole information that you have for this problem, but in general, I would approach it in the following way:

$1)$ On the first layer, I would assume independence between the patients that arrive and I would consider each arrival as a Bernoulli trial

$$visit_{i}\sim Bern(p), i = 1,...,n$$

where $i$ denotes a patient, and $p$ is the probability of visit (arrival).

$2)$ On the second layer, I would consider if a patient is hospitalized with the use of Bernoulli,

$$receive_{i} \sim Bern(visit_{i}  \times \phi) $$

where $\phi$ is the probability of getting into a slot (getting hospitalized).

---

The independence assumption might help to aggregate information and maybe derive some Binomial forms. Also, this formulation might be considered a state-space model. But again what I wrote might be tottaly wrong for what you are looking, hope that gave some ideas.

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer! I'm missing how your model takes in account the limited number of slots, and for what quantity $patient_i$ stands for. BTW, these patients don't get hospitalized, they just get the visited. But given some time constrains, just a limited number of visits (i.e., the slots) can be done in a certain amount of time, the others need to be booked later in time. I think the ideal would be a sort of bound Poisson model with a upper limit, but I'm not aware it exists.

Comment: Oops instead of $patient_{i}$ there should be $visit_{i}$. I see, ok so for a visit to happen, i.e to receive a slot, let's denote that as $receive_{i} \sim Bern(visit_{i},\phi)$. Now in order to take into the fixed number of slots, you could do something of the form, let $M$ the total number of slots, then $receive_{i} \sim Bern(\frac{(M-\sum_{j<i} visit_{j})}{M}\times \phi)$, so if no slots are available i.e. $\sum_{j<i}visit_{j} = M$ then with probability $0$ will get into a slot.

Comment: Yes, a Poisson would be also a good choice. I know that there is the zero-truncated poisson, but I do not know if you can truncate it into different intervals.

Comment: Nice model! just a question. I misunderstood or this model requires both positive and negative observations? I have only the number of visits while the negatives are, well, the rest of the population that doesn't need it. BTW, I was silly, because I just found that an upper truncated Poisson model actually exists (at least in brms/stan), but it is hard to make it converge...

Comment: It only needs counts, what do you refer to as positive and negative observations?? Yeah, in Stan if I remember well you can always define their support with $<lower=0,upper=Slots>$. There are diagnostics that tell you why it didn't converge, might be an iteration problem or tree depth problem, there is a really good manual I think.

Comment: Bernoulli expects 0 or 1 as data, how do I use the total number of visits in your model?

Comment: Let's say that the available people that might want to visit is $N$, then because $visit_{i}$ are independent, you can take their product $\prod_{i}p(visit_{i}) = \prod_{i}p^{visit_{i}}(1-p)^{1-visit_{i}}= p^{Total_Visits}(1-p)^{N-Total_Visits}$

Comment: The problem is that I don't know N! I can't use the whole population because the $p$ of getting sick or not is different from that of getting a slot, with the second being very high since the slots in a given period never get saturated.

Comment: Regarding the convergence of the Poisson, I just have two observation with low counts in each... doing Bayesian model comparison does prefer the original Binomial model and I think I'll use that for now since this is a pilot study and we hope to bring more hospital in; I'll justify it as the probability of filling up the slots which is related to the incidence, assuming that the slots are never totally filled up. But I'll cite the limitation and the alternative model in the discussion.

Comment: That's is good I wish you great research results!!